# Hide already selected options in the dropdown

Tags: input, dropdown, multi-selection, drop-down-list, choices

In the case of a multi-select field, I would like to know the best practice:

- Hide the choices that have already been selected (the list gets smaller as you go along)[image][image]
- Leave the choices already selected with a "selected" status [image]

In which case use what?

Answer (score 1):

*Leave the choices already selected with a "selected" status* causes the user to be forced to scroll down to see the other items, personally I see it as irrelevant noise.

[1001fonts.com](https://www.1001fonts.com/) has some possible solutions:

- The chosen elements are integrated into the list field
- They have the `X` icon to deselect
- There's an optimized use of space when using words in paragraph instead of the vertical list
- The list ranks the options to choose using typographic variables:
  bolder on top and lighter at the bottom
- There are buttons to show more or less options

[image]